# Periods in Strongly Connected Digraph

Tags: graph-theory

Let $D$ be a digraph. Define the period of a vertex $v \in V(D)$, denoted $per(v)$ to be the gcd of the lengths of all closed walks containing $v$.

Theorem: $D$ is a strongly connected digraph $\implies$ $\forall x,y \in V(D). per(x) = per(y)$

I am not sure how to prove this. Trying to break down the set of closed walk lengths containing $x$ into a union of walk lengths which do not include $y$ and those which do include $y$ has not gotten me very far. Another approach was to do induction on a set of closed walk lengths, starting with 2... $x \rightarrow y$ and $x \leftarrow y$, but this has also not gotten me anywhere. Is there a useful lemma or something?

Answer (score 1):

For any two vertices $x,y$ in $D$ there exist a closed walk $x\rightarrow y\rightarrow x$ and let this walk be $w$ have length $m$. Then we know $per(x)|m$ and $per(y)|m$.

Consider any closed walk $p$ that $x$ is in, let its length be $l$ then $per(x)|l$ and since $y\rightarrow x\rightarrow p\rightarrow x\rightarrow y$ is also a closed walk of length $l+m$ we know $per(y)|l+m$. Also since $per(y)|m$ we can get $per(y)|l$.

Hence both $per(x)$ and $per(y)$ divides the lengths of all closed walks containing $x$ and similarly we can show both of them divides the length of all closed walks containing $y$ so they are both equal to the $gcd$ of all walks containing either $x$ or $y$.